# Javascript : Usage of Object variable

Tags: javascript

I am using for loop to declare some objects,
and it looks like below

```
var variables = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  variables['data' + i] = i;

}
```

And after i used these method i can use these variable like below

```
   console.log(variables); //call all
   console.log(variables.data1); //call Single
```

But i am wondering if i am able to call all in another way like

```
  var variables = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      variables['data' + i] = i;

      //maybe i could export all data this way?
      var result = variables.data+i 

    }
```

I am doing this becuase i have speical usage of

```
var result = [variables.data0,variables.data1,variables.data2]
```

i want to use a loop to do this.

Comment: You can't use dot notation like that, use bracket notation: `var result = variables['data'+i]`.

Comment: *Before the loop:* `var result = [];` and then *in* the loop `result.push(variables['data'+i]);` (Sorry - I may have been a bit hasty in closing this as a duplicate. The linked question covers the access of property names using a variable, but not the part about adding to the array.)

Comment: console.log(seriesbb['data'+i]) returns undefine

Comment: `seriesbb` isn't shown in your question at all.

Comment: OPPS SORRY , i mean (variables['data'+i]), but i solve it now, according your method @nnnnnn